# Error with IPFS COR

Tags: ssl, https, cors, cross-domain, ipfs

When trying to use IPFS from my localhost I am having trouble accessing the IPFS service. I tried setting my config to accept the localhost and all server stuff, but nothing seems to work.

The error:

Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/files/stat?arg=0x6db883c6f3b2824d26f3b2e9c30256b490d125b10a3942f49a1ac715dd2def89&stream-channels=true: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

IPFS Config:

```
{
  "API": {
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Addresses": {
    "API": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
    "Announce": [],
    "Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080",
    "NoAnnounce": [],
    "Swarm": [
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
      "/ip6/::/tcp/4001"
    ]
  },
  "Bootstrap": [
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmNnooDu7bfjPFoTZYxMNLWUQJyrVwtbZg5gBMjTezGAJN",
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmQCU2EcMqAqQPR2i9bChDtGNJchTbq5TbXJJ16u19uLTa",
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmbLHAnMoJPWSCR5Zhtx6BHJX9KiKNN6tpvbUcqanj75Nb",
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmcZf59bWwK5XFi76CZX8cbJ4BhTzzA3gU1ZjYZcYW3dwt",
    "/ip4/104.131.131.82/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmaCpDMGvV2BGHeYERUEnRQAwe3N8SzbUtfsmvsqQLuvuJ",
    "/ip4/104.236.179.241/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLPppuBtQSGwKDZT2M73ULpjvfd3aZ6ha4oFGL1KrGM",
    "/ip4/128.199.219.111/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLSafTMBsPKadTEgaXctDQVcqN88CNLHXMkTNwMKPnu",
    "/ip4/104.236.76.40/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLV4Bbm51jM9C4gDYZQ9Cy3U6aXMJDAbzgu2fzaDs64",
    "/ip4/178.62.158.247/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLer265NRgSp2LA3dPaeykiS1J6DifTC88f5uVQKNAd",
    "/ip6/2604:a880:1:20::203:d001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLPppuBtQSGwKDZT2M73ULpjvfd3aZ6ha4oFGL1KrGM",
    "/ip6/2400:6180:0:d0::151:6001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLSafTMBsPKadTEgaXctDQVcqN88CNLHXMkTNwMKPnu",
    "/ip6/2604:a880:800:10::4a:5001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLV4Bbm51jM9C4gDYZQ9Cy3U6aXMJDAbzgu2fzaDs64",
    "/ip6/2a03:b0c0:0:1010::23:1001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLer265NRgSp2LA3dPaeykiS1J6DifTC88f5uVQKNAd"
  ],
  "Datastore": {
    "BloomFilterSize": 0,
    "GCPeriod": "1h",
    "HashOnRead": false,
    "Spec": {
      "mounts": [
        {
          "child": {
            "path": "blocks",
            "shardFunc": "/repo/flatfs/shard/v1/next-to-last/2",
            "sync": true,
            "type": "flatfs"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/blocks",
          "prefix": "flatfs.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        },
        {
          "child": {
            "compression": "none",
            "path": "datastore",
            "type": "levelds"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/",
          "prefix": "leveldb.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        }
      ],
      "type": "mount"
    },
    "StorageGCWatermark": 90,
    "StorageMax": "10GB"
  },
  "Discovery": {
    "MDNS": {
      "Enabled": true,
      "Interval": 10
    }
  },
  "Experimental": {
    "FilestoreEnabled": false,
    "Libp2pStreamMounting": false,
    "ShardingEnabled": false
  },
  "Gateway": {
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Range"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "localhost:63342"
      ]
    },
    "PathPrefixes": [],
    "RootRedirect": "",
    "Writable": false
  },
  "Identity": {
    "PeerID": "QmRgQdig4Z4QNEqs5kp45bmq6gTtWi2qpN2WFBX7hFsenm"
  },
  "Ipns": {
    "RecordLifetime": "",
    "RepublishPeriod": "",
    "ResolveCacheSize": 128
  },
  "Mounts": {
    "FuseAllowOther": false,
    "IPFS": "/ipfs",
    "IPNS": "/ipns"
  },
  "Reprovider": {
    "Interval": "12h",
    "Strategy": "all"
  },
  "Swarm": {
    "AddrFilters": null,
    "ConnMgr": {
      "GracePeriod": "20s",
      "HighWater": 900,
      "LowWater": 600,
      "Type": "basic"
    },
    "DisableBandwidthMetrics": false,
    "DisableNatPortMap": false,
    "DisableRelay": false,
    "EnableRelayHop": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben, try replacing 127.0.0.1 with localhost. go-ipfs whitelists localhost only. Also check https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api/#cors

Answer (score 0):

my answer might come very late, however I am trying to solve some CORS issues with IPFS on my end; therefore I might have a solution for you:

by running:

```sh
# please update origin according to your setup...
origin=http://localhost:63342
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["'"$origin"'", "http://127.0.0.1:8080","http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:48084", "https://gateway.ipfs.io", "https://webui.ipfs.io"]'

ipfs config API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

and restarting your ipfs daemon it might fix it

if the "fetch" button in the following linked page works : you are all set ! https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXkhGQNruk3XcGsidCzQbcNQ5a8oHWneHZXkPvWB26RbP/

Answer (score 0):

This Command Works for me

> ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin
> '["'"$origin"'", "http://127.0.0.1:8080","http://localhost:3000"]'

you can allow the request from multiple origins